# Xamarin IOS get iBeacon Advertisement data

Tags: ios, xamarin, bluetooth-lowenergy, beacon

I'm trying to read the information written in the advertisement of an iBeacon and I'm always having null values with IOS.
I've already developed an Android app that works correctly, in the OnScanResult() I get the ScanRecord with all the info I need.

The same is not working on IOS, has anyone found a way to read this data?

Thanks a lot,
Gianluca

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately **iOS blocks accessing the raw Bluetooth packet data of any BLE advertisement that matches the iBeacon format.**  The operating system actually truncates the data field for the packet when it matches iBeacon.

This appears to be an Intentional design by Apple , perhaps intended to prevent reading any unknown iBeacon Proximity UUID.  Apple's native APIs require you to know the Proximity UUiD up front.

This is a little silly, because as you have seen, Android has no such restriction.  But you can't argue with Apple!

More info in my blog post here: http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2013/10/21/corebluetooth-doesnt-let-you-see-ibeacons